# How to use filter function for broadcast variable in Pyspark

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata

When I am trying to filter broadcasted value with below command is not working. Please help me with the correct approach

```
from pyspark.sql import *
spark=SparkSession.builder.appName("broadcast variable").getOrCreate()

states={"CA":"California" , "NY":"Newyork" , "FL":"Florida"}
broadcaststates = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(states)
print(broadcaststates.value)

data = [("James","Smith","USA","CA"),
    ("Michael","Rose","USA","NY"),
    ("Robert","Williams","USA","CA"),
    ("Maria","Jones","USA","FL")
  ]

columns=["firstname","lastname","country","statename"]

df=spark.createDataFrame(data=data,schema=columns)
df.printSchema()
df.show(truncate=False)

def state_convert(code):
    return broadcaststates.value[code]

result=df.rdd.map(lambda x : (x[0],x[1],x[2],state_convert(x[3]))).toDF(columns)

result.show(truncate=False)

fiterDF=df.where(df['states'].isin(broadcaststates.value)))
```

Comment: Everything works for me. I just needed to change the lastline to `fiterDF=df.where(df['statename'].isin(list(broadcaststates.value.keys())))`

Comment: have you found an answer?

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two ways to use your broadcasted dictionary. By unboxing the key set with `*` or by turning it into a list with `list`:

```py
df.where(df['statename'].isin(*broadcaststates.value.keys())).show()
df.where(df['statename'].isin(list(broadcaststates.value.keys()))).show()
```

**BUT** there is no broadcasting happening here. Spark would do the exact same thing by simply using `states.keys()` directly. Indeed, have a look a the result of explain:

```py
df.where(df['statename'].isin(list(broadcaststates.value.keys()))).explain()
```

```
== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Filter statename#3 IN (CA,NY,FL)
+- *(1) Scan ExistingRDD[firstname#0,lastname#1,country#2,statename#3]
```

The key set is not broadcasted to the executors but instead embedded within the execution plan. This is perfectly fine if `states` is not too big. If `states` is very big however, it might cause an `OutOfMemoryError`. In that case, it might be more efficient to actually broadcast `states` and use it within a UDF as follows:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import BooleanType

isin_states = F.udf(lambda x : x in broadcaststates.value, BooleanType())
# the variable is broadcasted and not embedded within the execution plan
df.where(isin_states(df['statename'])).show()
```